# ThreeJS: Find neighbor faces in PlaneBufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking for a better/faster way to find the neighbor faces (that share the same edge) in my `PlaneBufferGeometry`. Currently my `THREE.Raycaster` intersects fine with my object (using `intersectObject`). But I need to find all surrounding faces.

At this moment I use the following dirty way to find the 'next door' faces. It works well in my scenario, but doesn't feel right:

```js
let rc = new THREE.Raycaster();
let intersects = [];
for (let i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
    for (let j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
        let v = new THREE.Vector3(x + i, y, z + j);
        rc.set(v, new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0));
        rc.near = 0;
        rc.far = 2;
        let subIntersects = rc.intersectObject(mesh);
        for (let n = 0; n < subIntersects.length; n++) {
            intersects.push(subIntersects[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there for instance a way to quickly find these faces in the `mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array`?
Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If by neighbor faces you mean faces with common vertices, there are several algorithms but no nuilt-in method in three.js. Easiest way is get all faces in geometry and filter them by faces with common vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I mean all faces that share the same edge. To get the them all might take a while because there are over 50k items in the position array.

Comment: If searching 50k items is too slow you could build a map of edges to things that share them at init time so then once you know an edge you can just look in the map to find the neighbors. Or a map of faces to neighboring faces. Also, given that it's a plane you should just be able to calculate the neightbors. Just go [look in the THREE.js code for the organization of triangles](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/f97e03ccd2f01aa65b54e4ceb204e3048433593a/src/geometries/PlaneGeometry.js#L74).

Comment: Doesn't have geometry built-in .faces property with an array of all faces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned 50k items in the position array. That doens't seem too slow to me. This example is only 10x10 so 100 items in the array so it's easy to see it's working, but I had it set to 200x200 which is 40k items and it seemed fast enough?

```js
'use strict';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 60;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 200;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 1;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('#444');

  scene.add(camera);

  const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1, 20, 20);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'blue'});
  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, material);
  scene.add(plane);
  
  const edgeGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const positionNumComponents = 3;
  edgeGeometry.setAttribute('position', planeGeometry.getAttribute('position'));
  edgeGeometry.setIndex([]);
  const edgeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
     color: 'yellow', 
     wireframe: true,
     depthTest: false,
  });
  const edges = new THREE.Mesh(edgeGeometry, edgeMaterial);
  scene.add(edges);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  class PickHelper {
    constructor() {
      this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    }
    pick(normalizedPosition, scene, camera, time) {
      // cast a ray through the frustum
      this.raycaster.setFromCamera(normalizedPosition, camera);
      // get the list of objects the ray intersected
      const intersectedObjects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, [plane]);
      if (intersectedObjects.length) {
        // pick the first object. It's the closest one
        const intersection = intersectedObjects[0];
        const faceIndex = intersection.faceIndex;
        const indexAttribute = planeGeometry.getIndex();
        const indices = indexAttribute.array;
        const vertIds = indices.slice(faceIndex * 3, faceIndex * 3 + 3);
        const neighbors = []; // note: self will be added to list
        for (let i = 0; i < indices.length; i += 3) {
          for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            const p0Ndx = indices[i + j];
            const p1Ndx = indices[i + (j + 1) % 3];
            if ((p0Ndx === vertIds[0] && p1Ndx === vertIds[1]) ||
                (p0Ndx === vertIds[1] && p1Ndx === vertIds[0]) ||
                (p0Ndx === vertIds[1] && p1Ndx === vertIds[2]) ||
                (p0Ndx === vertIds[2] && p1Ndx === vertIds[1]) ||
                (p0Ndx === vertIds[2] && p1Ndx === vertIds[0]) ||
                (p0Ndx === vertIds[0] && p1Ndx === vertIds[2])) {
                neighbors.push(...indices.slice(i, i + 3));
                break;
            }
          }
        }
        const edgeIndices = edgeGeometry.getIndex();
        edgeIndices.array = new Uint16Array(neighbors);
        edgeIndices.count = neighbors.length;
        edgeIndices.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    }
  }

  const pickPosition = {x: 0, y: 0};
  const pickHelper = new PickHelper();
  clearPickPosition();

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    pickHelper.pick(pickPosition, scene, camera, time);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  function getCanvasRelativePosition(event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: event.clientX - rect.left,
      y: event.clientY - rect.top,
    };
  }

  function setPickPosition(event) {
    const pos = getCanvasRelativePosition(event);
    pickPosition.x = (pos.x / canvas.clientWidth ) *  2 - 1;
    pickPosition.y = (pos.y / canvas.clientHeight) * -2 + 1;  // note we flip Y
  }

  function clearPickPosition() {
    // unlike the mouse which always has a position
    // if the user stops touching the screen we want
    // to stop picking. For now we just pick a value
    // unlikely to pick something
    pickPosition.x = -100000;
    pickPosition.y = -100000;
  }
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', setPickPosition);
  window.addEventListener('mouseout', clearPickPosition);
  window.addEventListener('mouseleave', clearPickPosition);

  window.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    // prevent the window from scrolling
    event.preventDefault();
    setPickPosition(event.touches[0]);
  }, {passive: false});

  window.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
    setPickPosition(event.touches[0]);
  });

  window.addEventListener('touchend', clearPickPosition);
}

main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r112/build/three.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Like I mentioned in the comment. If you know it's `PlaneBufferGeometry` then you can look in the three.js code and see the exact layout of faces so given a faceIndex you can just compute the neighbors directly. The code above is generic, at least for BufferGeometry with an index.

Looking at the code I'm pretty sure it's

```
// it looks like this is the grid order for PlaneBufferGeometry
//
//  b --c
//  |\\1|
//  |0\\|
//  a-- d


const facesAcrossRow = planeGeometry.parameters.widthSegments * 2;
const col = faceIndex % facesAcrossRow
const row = faceIndex / facesAcrossRow | 0;

const neighboringFaceIndices = [];

// check left face
if (col > 0) {
  neighboringFaceIndices.push(row * facesAcrossRow + col - 1);
}

// check right face
if (col < facesAcrossRow - 1) {
  neighboringFaceIndices.push(row * facesAcrossRow + col + 1);
}

// check up. there can only be one up if we're in an odd triangle (b,c,d)
if (col % 2 && row < planeGeometry.parameters.heightSegments) {
  // add the even neighbor in the next row
  neighboringFaceIndices.push((row + 1) * facesAcrossRow + col - 1);
}

// check down. there can only be one down if we're in an even triangle (a,b,d)
if (col % 2 === 0 && row > 0) {
  // add the odd neighbor in the previous row
  neighboringFaceIndices.push((row - 1) * facesAcrossRow + col + 1);
}
```

Trying that out

```js
'use strict';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 60;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 200;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 1;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('#444');

  scene.add(camera);

  const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1, 20, 20);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'blue'});
  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, material);
  scene.add(plane);
  
  const edgeGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const positionNumComponents = 3;
  edgeGeometry.setAttribute('position', planeGeometry.getAttribute('position'));
  edgeGeometry.setIndex([]);
  const edgeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
     color: 'yellow', 
     wireframe: true,
     depthTest: false,
  });
  const edges = new THREE.Mesh(edgeGeometry, edgeMaterial);
  scene.add(edges);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  class PickHelper {
    constructor() {
      this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    }
    pick(normalizedPosition, scene, camera, time) {
      // cast a ray through the frustum
      this.raycaster.setFromCamera(normalizedPosition, camera);
      // get the list of objects the ray intersected
      const intersectedObjects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, [plane]);
      if (intersectedObjects.length) {
        // pick the first object. It's the closest one
        const intersection = intersectedObjects[0];
        const faceIndex = intersection.faceIndex;
        const indexAttribute = planeGeometry.getIndex();
        const indices = indexAttribute.array;
        
        // it looks like this is the grid order for PlaneBufferGeometry
        //
        //  b --c
        //  |\\1|
        //  |0\\|
        //  a-- d

        const facesAcrossRow = planeGeometry.parameters.widthSegments * 2;
        const col = faceIndex % facesAcrossRow
        const row = faceIndex / facesAcrossRow | 0;

        const neighboringFaceIndices = [];

        // check left face
        if (col > 0) {
          neighboringFaceIndices.push(row * facesAcrossRow + col - 1);
        }

        // check right face
        if (col < facesAcrossRow - 1) {
          neighboringFaceIndices.push(row * facesAcrossRow + col + 1);
        }

        // check up. there can only be one up if we're in an odd triangle (b,c,d)
        if (col % 2 && row < planeGeometry.parameters.heightSegments) {
          // add the even neighbor in the next row
          neighboringFaceIndices.push((row + 1) * facesAcrossRow + col - 1);
        }

        // check down. there can only be one down if we're in an even triangle (a,b,d)
        if (col % 2 === 0 && row > 0) {
          // add the odd neighbor in the previous row
          neighboringFaceIndices.push((row - 1) * facesAcrossRow + col + 1);
        }        
        
        const neighbors = [];
        for (const faceIndex of neighboringFaceIndices) {
          neighbors.push(...indices.slice(faceIndex * 3, faceIndex * 3 + 3));
        }
        const edgeIndices = edgeGeometry.getIndex();
        edgeIndices.array = new Uint16Array(neighbors);
        edgeIndices.count = neighbors.length;
        edgeIndices.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    }
  }

  const pickPosition = {x: 0, y: 0};
  const pickHelper = new PickHelper();
  clearPickPosition();

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    pickHelper.pick(pickPosition, scene, camera, time);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  function getCanvasRelativePosition(event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: event.clientX - rect.left,
      y: event.clientY - rect.top,
    };
  }

  function setPickPosition(event) {
    const pos = getCanvasRelativePosition(event);
    pickPosition.x = (pos.x / canvas.clientWidth ) *  2 - 1;
    pickPosition.y = (pos.y / canvas.clientHeight) * -2 + 1;  // note we flip Y
  }

  function clearPickPosition() {
    // unlike the mouse which always has a position
    // if the user stops touching the screen we want
    // to stop picking. For now we just pick a value
    // unlikely to pick something
    pickPosition.x = -100000;
    pickPosition.y = -100000;
  }
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', setPickPosition);
  window.addEventListener('mouseout', clearPickPosition);
  window.addEventListener('mouseleave', clearPickPosition);

  window.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    // prevent the window from scrolling
    event.preventDefault();
    setPickPosition(event.touches[0]);
  }, {passive: false});

  window.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
    setPickPosition(event.touches[0]);
  });

  window.addEventListener('touchend', clearPickPosition);
}

main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r112/build/three.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

For something more complex than a PlaneBufferGeometry 
you could also pre-generate a map of faceIndexs to neighbors if the code at the top is too slow.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your really detailed answer. It's for sure something I can somehow embed in my scenario. I might go for a pre-generated map. Thanks again.